# Fill in missing pandas data with non-missing value with the same id but avoiding certain values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nan, fill

I got 3 columns in particular that are missing data from a left join on 2 keys.

I want to fill in missing data with the data of the same column, but of a row with the same id (which is one of the 2 keys) and only for the 'Size' column.

The fact is that I can't use `df['Size'] = df.groupby('Id')['Size'].ffill()` since I want to avoid using the sizes that contains the 'LAB' string (ignoring case), so I can use only the records which `Size = ['XL', 'L', 'M', 'MS', 'S', 'XS']`.

**Don't worry about which 'Size' is the correct. In the dataframe there will only be at most 2 options (it will always be only one valid size of the list I mentioned before and sometimes a string that contains 'LAB' in some case**

Imagine the actual dataframe is something like this:

```
Id    |    Place   | ... |   Size   |   Building  |   Wing   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
...      ...         ...     ...         ...          ...
64587    America     ...     LaB.PCD     A            North
64587    America     ...     XL          C            East
64587    Africa      ...     nan         nan          nan
64587    Africa      ...     nan         nan          nan
...        ...       ...     ...         ...          ...
```

So the desired output should be:

```
Id    |  Place   | ... |   Size   |   Building  |   Wing   |
-----------------------------------------------------------
...      ...       ...     ...         ...            ...
64587    America   ...     LaB.PCD     A              North
64587    America   ...     XL          C              East
64587    Africa    ...     XL          nan            nan
64587    Africa    ...     XL          nan            nan
...      ...       ...     ...         ...            ...
```